# How can I share a string through email and imessage from my iOS app?

Tags: ios, objective-c

My webview opens up a specific URL, and I have it set up where if a user taps the search button, the following dialogue appears:

[image]

How do I allow a user to share the url string when they tap each respective button? This is what I have so far:

```
- (IBAction)shareButtonAction:(id)sender {
    UIActionSheet *popup = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Select Sharing option:" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:
                            @"Share via E-mail",
                            @"Share via iMessage",
                            nil];
    popup.tag = 1;
    [popup showInView:[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow];
}

- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)popup clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

    switch (popup.tag) {
        case 1: {
            switch (buttonIndex) {
                case 0:
                    NSLog(@"lets share on email");
                    break;
                case 1:
                    NSLog(@"lets share on iMessage");
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            break;
        }
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Ckouta Yup, that was it, thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sharing by email and message is using the same framework, these is the steps:

1. Add the framework `MessageUI` into your project.
2. Import the header in your class: `#import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>`
3. Implements the sharing code

Use [MFMailComposeViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/index.html) to share by email:

```
if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {
    MFMailComposeViewController *mailController = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    [mailController setMailComposeDelegate:self];
    [mailController setSubject:@"Your subject"];
    [mailController setToRecipients:@[@"email1", @"email2"];
    [mailController setMessageBody:@"Your body" isHTML:NO];
    [self presentViewController:mailController animated:YES completion:nil];
}

// Then implement the delegate method
- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

And [MFMessageComposeViewController](https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/ios/documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMessageComposeViewController_class/index.html) to share by message:

```
if ([MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText]) {
    MFMessageComposeViewController *messageController = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];
    [messageController setMessageComposeDelegate:self];
    [messageController setRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"recipient"]];
    [messageController setBody:@"Your body"];
    [self presentViewController:messageController animated:NO completion:nil];
}

// Then implement the delegate method
- (void)messageComposeViewController:(MFMessageComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MessageComposeResult)result {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```